How to access elements in a clone of group in Inkscape
In an svg map exported from Openstreetmap some of the objects (mostly borders) appear in a

Clone of Group of 213 objects, clipped, masked in layer #surface1

I would like to modify those objects but cannot select them in any way I tried.
Ctrl+Shift+G to ungroup them did not work either.
How can I access these objects?

A clone isn't a group, so ungrouping won't work here.  At the very least you'd need to unlink the clone first before you can edit what's in the group.
Edit > Clone > Unlink clone
There's also a possibility that a clone could contain additional clones, so you'd also need to unlink these if you want to edit them.
The same goes for clips and masks, you may also have to release those.
Object > Clip > Release clip
Object > Mask > Release mask
Note that how practical it is to edit an SVG often depends on its construction. There are no guarantees that everything will be fully editable or easy to edit, even using the techniques I mentioned above, especially if it was made in software other than Inkscape. The more you try to deconstruct such SVGs, the more messy things can get.
If there's any text in the SVG, you might find it's uneditable in Inkscape. In such cases, the easiest option is often to delete it and retype.
